# XNA changing 200 or so tiles pixels

Tags: xna-4.0, pixel

Hey guys i thought this was going to be a 1second thing to do, currently i have a tileset for a 2d game and depending on the terrain it calls these tile sets. and the tile sets are colour coded pink is the material and blue is the material adjacent to the tile.

so far when terrain changes or on load up i draw the tiles on the screen and any new tiles as i move. this is all fine and works very well, but when i have like 50 grass tiles that need to be changed from pink to green and 75 dirt tiles which need to be changed from pink to grey i have a issue.

it only appears the first tile is changed then every other tile infront or before that tile is the same colour as the first colour.

ill give you an example in code what im doing

```
Color[] storePixels = new Color[50 * 50];

for(int y = 0; y < 100; y ++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
         tileTexture[y,x].GetData(storePixels);

         for(int i = 0; i < storePixels.Length; i ++)
         {
              if(tileMaterial[y,x] == "DIRT")
              {
                  storePixels[i] = new Color(100,100,100);
              }
              if(tileMaterial[y,x] == "GRASS")
              {
                  storePixels[i] = new Color(0,255,0);
              }
        }
        tileTexture[y,x].SetData(storePixels);
    }
}
```

To me i cant see why this wont work. i assume maybe i need to reset the storePixels which i have tried but still it does not create green if its grass or grey if its dirt.

Please let me know if you know why this is not working thank you for your time and thank you in advance :)

OK! i figured it out im calling the same Image in my content folder

```
for(int y = 0; y < 100; y ++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x ++)
    {
         tileTexture[y,x] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("tile");
    }
}
```

so now we are getting somewere we know why the problem is being cuassed as i change the Texture2D through SetData() it actually changes this tile texture2D directly and everything else that calls it will always be changed.

i cannot call it in a loop, i only call it at startup i could try store a copy of the texture2D and then change it.

i dunno does anyone have any further solutions to help solve this problem? thanks for you time :)

Answer (score 0):

That code is a bad idea...

you can work with only one white texture...

```
WhiteTex = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice,1,1);
WhiteTex.SetData<Color>(new Color[] {Color.White };
```

you can draw tiles this way...

```
Enum MaterialTypes { Dirt, Grass }
static readonly Dictionary<int, Color> MaterialTypeToColor = new Dictionary() { {0, new Color(100,100,100)}, {1, new Color(0,255,0) }};

for(int y = 0; y < 100; y ++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {            
         batch.Draw(whiteTex, new Rectangle(x*50,y*50, 50,50), null, (MaterialTypeToColor[ (int) tileMaterial[y,x]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the drawing code is drawing each texture2D in the y,x array                 for example                                                                       for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++)                                                               {                                                                                         for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)                                               {                                                                                      spriteBatch.Draw(tileTexture[y,x],rectangle,Color.White);

Comment: ive tried using a specific storePixel colour for each texture2D, the output im recieving for example i tell it only to draw and change tile 0,0 but it randomly change 4,4 5,9 8,1 1,1 and like 70% of the other tiles randomly each time. i spent a whole day 24 trying to bug fix this with no success and im thinking im either missing something or XNA cant draw a grid of lots of tiles

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++) 
{ 
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) 
    { 
        spriteBatch.Draw(tileTexture[y,x],rectangle,Color.White);
    }
}
```

this is how i am drawing my grid